# Why do I get Run-time Error 91 in this MS Access code?

Tags: vba, ms-access

So, I have a MS Access database application. In this application is a main form, which contains a number of subforms. One form in particular has a drop down box that I populate with dates from a database query. When one of these dates is selected, I run a subroutine that is supposed to update a recordset on the subform with history information. Below is some edited code (just removed the large number of fields from the queries)

```
Private Sub pickdate_AfterUpdate()
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'   Add review history by selected date
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT model, entered_date FROM history WHERE entered_date=#" & Me.pickdate.value & "# ORDER BY model DESC", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

If rs.BOF = False Then rs.MoveFirst
While rs.EOF = False

    Forms!main!histories.Form.Recordset.AddNew
    Forms!main!histories.Form.Recordset![model] = rs![model]
    Forms!main!histories.Form.Recordset![entered_date] = rs![entered_date]
    Forms!main!histories.Form.Recordset.Update

    rs.MoveNext
Wend
End Sub
```

I get the error on the `Forms!main!histories.Form.Recordset.AddNew` line.

I have tried the following versions of that line:

```
Forms!main!histories.Form.Recordset.AddNew
main!histories.Form.Recordset.AddNew
histories.Form.Recordset.AddNew
Me.Form.Recordset.AddNew
Me.Recordset.AddNew
Me.AddNew
Me.main!histories.Form.Recordset.AddNew
Me!histories.Form.Recordset.Addnew
Me!main!histories.Form.Recordset.AddNew
```

I am literally at my wit's end trying to figure out where the issue is.
The subform has all the proper boxes to store the information. I have given them labels to match their database columns that will go into them. I've tried setting their control sources to the database column names and not setting them to anything. I've looked up a hundred different "solutions", none of which seem to either fit the problem or work.

I feel like I am overlooking something really easy.

Comment: Why are you not just running an append query? Why walk the recordset?

Comment: I agree with @Remou- add the rows to the underlying dataset, not through the form

Comment: I am pretty new to Access and VBA programming. This project is actually old legacy code that I have to maintain and add functionality to. The rest of the application uses the recordset walking for pretty much everything. I don't know how to do an append query.

Comment: The recordset underpinning your form needs to be the right type; it should be a DynaSet, not a ForwardOnly or Snapshot.  Error 91 is "Object Variable Not Set."

Comment: The form needs to be writable, and have the ability to add new records.  Are the CanWrite, CanRead, CanAdd etc.  flags all set to Yes in the Form Properties?

Comment: The query that is bound to the form needs to be writable.  Is it?

Comment: There are four fields in properties, all set to Yes: Allow Additions, Allow Deletions, Allow Edits, Allow Filters.

Comment: Can you manually update the subform? That is is the recordset editable?

Comment: Error 91 is object variable not set. Try `Me.histories.Form.` and make sure the subform contail is called histories, not the form contained.

Comment: I can edit the boxes, but they don't get linked to anything until after I run the query. However, I can't run the query because it says the object is not set. Also, when I do edit the boxes, it only takes one of the columns and puts it in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon you have problems with your names. Check all of them. Do not forget that a subform consists of two parts, the subform control and the form contained. These often have the same name, but not always. In the code you are using, you must have the name of the subform control, not the form contained. If entering data into the subform manually is not working properly, your controls are not bound.

This works for me on a sample table.

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT atext from table1 WHERE akey=21")

If rs.BOF = False Then rs.MoveFirst
While Not rs.EOF '= False
    Me.Table1_subform1.Form.Recordset.AddNew
    Me.Table1_subform1.Form.Recordset!AText = rs!AText
    Me.Table1_subform1.Form.Recordset.Update

    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

To run a query you could say:

```
sSQL="INSERT INTO NameOfTable (model, entered_date) " _
& "SELECT model, entered_date FROM history WHERE entered_date=#" _
& Me.pickdate.value & "#"

CurrentDB.execute, dbfailOnError
```

You can check the sql works in the query design window.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably what the problem is.  Were you able to reproduce the Error 91?

Comment: No, but I did not try all that hard :)

Comment: @Remou: Thanks for your help. After changing the names of everything and rewriting all the queries, I was still having issues. Until I turned of "Fetch Defaults" on the Property Sheet for the subform. I think the combination of your ideas and that change was what finally fixed it.

Comment: I am glad you have sorted that out. If you have fetch defaults, it seems you are using an ADP. If that is the case, it would be worth mentioning if you have any other problems.